# AS3 - Smooth images loaded in UILoader

Tags: actionscript-3, uiloader

The UILoader size is 200x200 pixels. but when I load large images to this small square (image sizes like 600x600 pixels), it looks like it isn't smooth. I've tried:

```
theUILoader.source = "a.png";
Bitmap(theUILoader.content).smoothing = true;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used UILoader but I assume that if you pass a string as source, the image needs to be loaded. Therefore you cannot just put `Bitmap(theUILoader.content).smoothing = true` - the image is not loaded. Try to put a listener on it, `Event.COMPLETE`. Then in the handler put the very same smoothing code.